# Confused with one of the steps for a bxslider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am confused about step 3 of adding a image slider to your webpage: http://bxslider.com/. Can anyone help? Here is a code bin of my html : http://codebin.org/view/3bd29e6d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add this to the bottom of your slider page (just before the closing `</body>` tag, or at least below your links to the jQuery library):

```
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://codebin.org/view/2f0ab415 I did this but it seems like i still get an error were there are 4 bullet point and then next to them there adre 4 error image icons. It seems like i am missing something. Any thoughts? Is it the image size that i am linking?

Comment: Your slider has a class of `.slider`. Change this to `.bxslider`, to match what the JS is looking for. You'll also need to load the bxSlider styles, either as a separate style sheet or just drop those styles into your main style sheet. also make sure that `/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js` is the actual path to your bsSlider script. If it isn't, update it to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple:

Step 3 is nothing but a `initializer`

You need to add the recommended js

```
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

and call the function in the page load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Use this in your code:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: http://codebin.org/view/2f0ab415 I did this but it seems like i still get an error were there are 4 bullet point and then next to them there adre 4 error image icons. It seems like i am missing something. Any thoughts? Is it the image size that i am linking?